# Attack secure domain controller in environment with unique username/password combinations

Tags: network, windows, penetration-test, domain-controller

I’ve already obtained local administrator on a domain user’s computer. Now, my target is one of the company’s domain controllers.

However, the domain controllers run no vulnerable services, and every username/password combination is unique across the domain, so pass-the-hash using Mimikatz doesn’t work.

Furthermore, no useful delegation tokens are found using Incognito on the local system.

What are my options from here, except carrying out man-in-the-middle attacks using tools like Responder?